# Null Exception on ViewPager Adapter - Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to implement ViewPager in Android with my adapter and getting this error, I've googled and everything seems fine but still my app is crashing, any help would be highly appreciated.

Adapter:

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            ChatFragment.create();
        case 1:
            EmptyFragment.create();
        case 2:
            StoryFragment.create();
    }
    return  null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

}

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View back = (View) findViewById(R.id.am_background_view);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.am_view_pager);
    MainPagerAdapter adapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<View
    android:id="@+id/am_background_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    />




<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/am_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

ChatFragment

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

public  static ChatFragment create() {
    return new ChatFragment();
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: pk.fastech.snappy.snappy, PID: 6148
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:380)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:375)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:103)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1182)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3158)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1599)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1891)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1487)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7450)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: `getItem` in your Adapter always returns null. Change it to `return ChatFragment.create();`

Comment: In this way I won't be able to swipe between my fragments, it will only show Chat fragment. Why is isn't getting into switch block?

Comment: The important part about my comment above was the missing `return` statement. I didn't mean actually change every line to `ChatFragment` :)

Comment: Sorry @KenWolf, my bad, I understood your answer wrong, though it was the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getItem` method is incorrect and always returns `null`.

You should change it to:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return ChatFragment.create();
        case 1:
            return EmptyFragment.create();
        case 2:
            return StoryFragment.create();
    }
    return null;
}
```

`return` in Java returns the result to the calling method - but you were not returning this result - it does not "stack".

Comment: Thank you so much, just started android development few days back and spent hours trying to figure out the solution.